# Convert stream transformer function into Mealy automaton in Haskell

Tags: haskell, stream, transformer-model

I work with streams:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)
```

Particularly, stream transformer functions:

```
f :: Stream a -> Stream b
```

I would like to make a Mealy automaton out of such a function:

```
data Mealy a b = Mealy (a -> (b, Mealy a b))
```

Is there a way to write such a function?

```
toMealy :: (Stream a -> Stream b) -> Mealy a b
```

I can't find a way. Although the other way works easily:

```
toStreamTransformer :: Mealy a b -> Stream a -> Stream b
```

Maybe I'm missing something trivial?

Comment: The problem I see is that there is no beginning point; every Mealy automaton comes from some previous automaton, but where does the first one come from? In other words, you need an explicit start state as an argument to `toMealy`.

Comment: You can certainly write a function `toMealy :: (Stream a -> Stream b) -> Mealy a b` if you don't care what it does, but I'm guessing you have something more specific in mind. But not every stream transformer can be produced by `toStreamTransformer`; only ones where the first N elements of the output only depend on the first N elements of the input for each N.

Comment: Its not an answer to your question, but you might take a look at Edward Kmetts "machine" package. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.6.1

Comment: @Paul Johnson I know of this package, but as you said, it does not seem to have a solution.

Comment: @Reid Barton You are right, so the reversal of toStreamTransformer has to be restricted, too. I see. Hmm, I wonder, if there is still a way of doing something close. Obviously, I only care about streams that are deterministic in the way you described it.

Comment: See the blog post [Programmatic translation to iteratees from pull-based code](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/programmatic-translation-to-iteratees.html) by Paul Chiusano. I also implemented something a bit like this in my [streaming-eversion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-eversion) library, only the transformation was not to Mealy machines; but to the `Fold` datatype of the [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.2.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer makes use of the `Stream` abstraction provided by the [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) package. This abstraction:

- Is a monad transformer, so you can put any monad under it.
- Has a return type separate from the elements produced by the stream. A value of this type is returned when the stream is exhausted.

Imagine you have a function like:

```
module Main where

import Streaming
import Streaming.Internal (Stream(Effect,Step,Return))
import Streaming.Prelude

transformation :: Monad m => Stream (Of Int) m r -> Stream (Of String) m r
transformation = undefined -- your code here
```

`transformation` changes a stream of `Int` values into a stream of `String` values. It is polymorphic on the base monad, which means the transformation itself is pure. It is polymorphic on the return type `r`, which means that the transformation always exhausts the source stream.

Now we write these auxiliary definitions:

```
data Feed a = Input a | EOF

trickster :: Monad m => Stream (Of a) (Stream ((->) (Feed a)) m) ()        
trickster = do
  r <- Effect (Step (Return . Return)) -- request a `Feed a` value
  case r of
      Input a -> Step (a :> trickster)
      EOF     -> Return ()
```

`trickster` is a bit strange. At the outer level, it is a stream that produces `a` values. But underneath, we have something like a `Free (->)` monad (here also implemented with `Stream`) that takes `a` values and emits them at the outer level.

What happens if we apply `trickster` to `transformation`, and then merge the two `Stream` layers using the [`unseparate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:unseparate) function?

```
machine :: Stream (Sum (Of String) ((->) (Feed Int))) Identity ()         
machine = unseparate (transformation trickster)
```

We can advance through `machine` using the [`inspect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3/docs/Streaming.html#v:inspect) function

```
inspect :: (Functor f, Monad m) => Stream f m r -> m (Either r (f (Stream f m r)))
```

Here's a scary type:

```
ghci> :t runIdentity (inspect machine)
runIdentity (inspect machine)
  :: Either
       ()
       (Sum
          (Of String)
          ((->) (Feed Int))
          (Stream (Sum (Of String) ((->) (Feed Int))) Identity ()))
```

It basically means that at a given step the machine either terminates (but the implementation of `trickster` ensures that it will never do that unless we pass `EOF`) or it produces a `String`, or requires us to enter an `Int` value.

(We could have done without `unseparate`, but the process of peeling the two `Stream` layers would have been more confusing.)

(Also, see the blog post [Programmatic translation to iteratees from pull-based code](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/programmatic-translation-to-iteratees.html) by Paul Chiusano for the original idea behind this code.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It took quite some time to understand. The blog-post helped a lot as well!

Comment: The definition of `trickster` is more complex than it needs to be because it accesses the internals of `Stream` to gain a bit of efficiency. You can substitute `r <- lift (yields id)` for `Effect (Step (Return . Return))`, `Input a -> yield a *> trickster` for `Input a -> Step (a :> trickster)` and `return ()` for `Return ()`. `Effect`, `Step` and `Return` are internal constructors from `Streaming.Internal` which are usually hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you're assuming that the stream transformer passed to `toMealy` is "deterministic" then you can get your Mealy machine started by, on input `a`, passing `a : e : e : ...` to the stream transformer (where `e = error "input stream transformer is not deterministic"`), and outputting the first element `b` of the output stream. Then modify your stream transformer to prepend `a` to its input and drop the first element (presumably `b`) of its output and recurse.

Or if you prefer you can use input `a : a : a : ...` instead; then you'll get a total function that doesn't detect whether the input is deterministic, but produces a Mealy machine that only generates the original stream transformer when it is.

This approach will take quadratic time in the number of steps you want to run the Mealy machine for; there might be something cleverer.